# How to convert blob to base64 JS on React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, base64, blob

I'm making a project that is a monorepo that the service returns a blob for React and React Native projects, in React it works normally because it's native to the language itself, but for React Native it doesn't work.

How can I use this js feature in React Native?

1- Pass a base64, but internally, it uses the FileReader() class that React Native doesn't understand either
2- Use the base-64 lib, but it expects a string as a parameter and when trying to convert the blob   into a string it doesn't work either because it needs an ArrayBuffer and React Native doesn't  understand either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.